# Send callback function from C# to C dll in struct

Tags: c#, c++, dll, native

I'm trying to send a struct that includes references for callbacks functions from C# to C++ native DLL, what wrong with what i'm doing>?, the struct passed!, all callbacks reference are not null but When call it I do no reach the C# functions from DLL:(

```
class Native_Wrraper
{
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate int LogMessageCallback(string mMyStruct);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate int ActionCompleteCallback(int actionId, int actionResult);
    [UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public delegate string GetFilePathCallback(string filter);
```

The strucure:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    public struct InitCallBacksStruct
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public LogMessageCallback logMessageCallback;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public ActionCompleteCallback actionCompleteCallback;

        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.FunctionPtr)]
        public GetFilePathCallback getPath;
        //UpdaterCallback updaterCallback;
    };

    [DllImport("_Wrraper.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int InitDll(InitCallBacksStruct mMyStruct);

    [DllImport("_Wrraper.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StartTestAPIDll(string TestHeader, int someNumber);
```

Here the call back functions that DLL should call (enter)

```
    public static int FuncLogMessageCallback(string mMyStruct)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public static int FuncActionCompleteCallback(int actionId, int actionResult)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    public static string FuncGetFilePathCallback(string filter)
    {
        return "The Call back worked!";
    }
}
```

The Test button:

```
    private void btnTest_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Native_Wrraper.InitCallBacksStruct str =  new Native_Wrraper.InitCallBacksStruct();
        str.actionCompleteCallback = new Native_Wrraper.ActionCompleteCallback(Native_Wrraper.FuncActionCompleteCallback);
        str.getPath = new Native_Wrraper.GetFilePathCallback(Native_Wrraper.FuncGetFilePathCallback);
        str.logMessageCallback = new Native_Wrraper.LogMessageCallback(Native_Wrraper.FuncLogMessageCallback);
        Native_Wrraper.InitDll(str);
        Native_Wrraper.StartTestAPIDll(DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), 0xEE);
    }
```

in C DLL:

The structure:

```
#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
typedef void (__stdcall * ActionCompleteCallback)(int actionId, int actionResult);
typedef char* (__stdcall * GetFilePathCallback)(char* filter);
typedef void (__stdcall * LogMessageCallback)(char* message);


//This structure include all the references to a call backs functions 
struct InitCallBacksStruct
{
    LogMessageCallback logMessageCallback;
    ActionCompleteCallback actionCompleteCallback;
    GetFilePathCallback getPath;
};

#endif
```

The API:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

#define DLL __declspec(dllexport)
DLL int InitDll(InitCallBacksStruct mMyStruct);
DLL int StartTestAPIDll( __in LPWSTR TestHeader, int someNumber);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Example of calling from DLL:

```
if(this->mInitCallBacksStruct.actionCompleteCallback)
{
    this->mInitCallBacksStruct.actionCompleteCallback(someNumber,0xCC);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Guys, CODE WORK perfect!!!

The issue was the breakpoint in C#!!! :)

Added MessageBox.Show and verify all works.

So this would be a template and/or answer for anyone who is looking for a solution to:

How to send list of callback functions references using one function call inside a structure to native DLL from C#.

> ONLY, be aware that you should keep the callback in C# somewhere globally and better static and not inside the btnTest_Click function! to make sure the reference will not gone, mean the reference to callback function should be global or static variable, for example:

```
static Native_Wrraper.ActionCompleteCallback refFunction = new Native_Wrraper.ActionCompleteCallback(Native_Wrraper.FuncGetFilePathCallback);
```

> then send it to DLL

```
str.actionCompleteCallback = refFunction
```

Good luck!
Joseph